# Custom Node type error: javax.jcr.ItemExistsException: jcr:propertyDefinition

Tags: aem, jcr

I am trying to register custom node type using CND file as follows -

```
  <ns='http://custom.namespace.com/ns'>

  [ns:CustomType] > nt:base
   orderable
   - title (String)
   - description (String)
   - sling:resourceType (String) = "myproject/components/test"
```

But I am getting this error : [image]

When I use only one property, for example either title or description or sling:resourceType then it works. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following config:

Remove `orderable`,

```
<'sling'='http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0'>
<'nt'='http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0'>
<ns='http://custom.namespace.com/ns'>

[ns:CustomType] > nt:base
   - title (String)
   - description (String)
   - sling:resourceType (String) = 'myproject/components/test'
```

Or extend from `nt:unstructered`:

```
<'sling'='http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0'>
<'nt'='http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0'>
<ns='http://custom.namespace.com/ns'>

[ns:CustomType] > nt:unstructered
   orderable
   - title (String)
   - description (String)
   - sling:resourceType (String) = 'myproject/components/test'
```

Comment: same error, it does not register all 3 properties, it only register first property

Comment: I had tried all the combination before, none of them worked. Did it work for you? I am on 6.4 SP2

Comment: @SumantaPakira, I have tried it on 6.4.2. Remove orderable or extend nt:unstructured